# does ASUS AMD crossfire motherboard support intel core i5 cpu?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-core-i5

I would like to know if ASUS Crosshair V Formula AM3+ AMD 990FX motherboard ( http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131735 ) support intel core i5 cpu?

In the manual it says:

```
CPU:
~~~
AMD AM3+ FX™/Phenom™ II/Athlon™ II/Sempron™ 100 Series Processors 
Supports AM3+ 32 nm CPU
Supports CPU up to 8 cores
Supports CPU up to 140 W
AMD Cool 'n' Quiet™ Technology
```

But, I am not sure, if it supports it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As you can see from the specifications, it supports AMD CPUs which use the AM3+ socket. Intel uses other sockets.

Comment: specifically the core i5 uses LGA 1155 sockets. They also have incompatible chipsets etc etc. Any attempt to install a core i5 system in said AM3+ system will result in much cussing, swearing, and at the minimum, much violence.